# unix removing or deleting in putty

Tags: unix

I was trying to remove a file, but I do not know why it does not work as usual

the following is what I type and outputs

[xxxxx@venus ~]$ ls

11.cpp;

[xxxxx@venus ~]$ rm 11.cpp

rm: cannot remove ‘11.cpp’: No such file or directory

and I also try rmdir and rm -f, it shows the same message. then I use vim to create a new file called 11.cpp; after it, I type ls again and I got 11.cpp and 11.cpp; and then no matter I type rm 11.cpp or 11.cpp;  11.cpp always can be deleted and 11.cpp; always reminds there.

can anyone help me figure out it. thank you!

Comment: There's an extra semicolon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a wild card, there may be some escaped characters.

```
rm 11.cp*
```

Or if you can autocomplete the filename, you can see what the filename is called:

```
rm 11<tab>
```

Also check what rm is hooked up to:

```
which rm
```

which could actually just rename files to ";" (to mark as delete) so that some OTHER process can remove them.

Comment: thank you! can I ask you what is escaped characters? I google it, but I did not quit get it. can you use my question as an example to explain. thank you so much!

Comment: Check out http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19829/special-character-in-filename-033oa or https://lwn.net/Articles/416824/ which have been causing users havoc for decades.  Just like MS's "Program Files" directory.